# Disable JIRA email notifications using the SOAP API

Tags: jira

Is there a way to disable email notifications in JIRA when making updates to fields using the SOAP API?

Answer (score 0):

updateProject() lets you change the permission scheme to None, but you have to provide all the other schemes when using this or they get cleared. And getting the other schemes proved troublesome as I recall